# divs with particular shape

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create an horizontal navigation bar with a shape like the one used in "team" and "cooperation" divs in this link. Does exist a library for that? [LINK](http://hitmo-studio.com/#hitmo)

Comment: That website uses background-images for that effect.

Comment: AFAICS only the "active" button gets a background image to make the "speech bubble" effect - the rest is all just rounded corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website uses background images to achieve the appearance, more specifically it uses a technique known as [spriting](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) (or CSS sprites).

The technique is essentially just the use of one image which contains multiple images, with each image used seperately. The single image is used by way of the `background-position` rule that allows you to essentially pick and choose which part of the large image you want to use. The primary aim of the technique is to reduce the quantity of HTTP requests in order to speed up loading of the page.

Please do refer to http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ for a better explanation.

Here is the sprite they use on the website you linked to:

http://hitmo-studio.com/images/sprites-set-1.png

You can see the four boxes across the top of the sprite image. Here's an example of how the second box (team) uses the correct part of the sprite image

```
.list-c li.team a {
background-position: -246px 0;
}
```

Comment: ah - **those** links - I was looking at the ones in the top menu bar!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for this, it's just CSS.

In the page you link to the site seems to use an [image sprite](http://hitmo-studio.com/images/sprites-set-1.png) for the background-images to create the illusion of a distorted (inset/outset triangles) shape, but it's possible to emulate that using compliant browsers that can deal with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements:

```
.box {
    width: 150px; /* or whatever */
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #f90; /* adjust to your taste */
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative; /* required to position the pseudo elements */
    margin: 0 auto; /* used to move the box off the edge of the page, adjust to taste */
}

.box::before {
    content: ''; /* required in order for the ::before to be visible on the page */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin: -25px 0 0 0; /* to position it vertically centred */
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #fff; /* forms the triangular shape on the left */
}

.box::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin: -25px -50px 0 0;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #f90;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a3LNF/1/).

Note that there are problems using this approach:

1. The background of the page can't show through the triangle on the left (since it's a solid white), if you make that triangle `transparent` then you'll see through the border but see only the background-color of the `.box` `div` element.
2. Positioning the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements with `position: absolute` means that these elements appear above the text in the `div`. So you'd probably need to adjust the `padding` of that `div` and the `border-width` of the pseudo-elements to reduce that problem, this is just a demonstration.